# Why do leaves turn yellowish and then dry?

Tags: diseases, beans

I have planted beans in approximately 10 inch (25 cm) pot with potting soil. I also water the pot regularly. The beans have grown well and started to flower but the leaves are turning yellowish. Is this some kind of disease or is the plant dying for some reason?

[image: plant with yellowish leaves/cheer tomato in the same pot]

Comment: I don't know what it is, but the tomato leaves seem to have the same problem. Look on the other side of the leaves and tell us if they have the same dots pattern or if it is more pronounced there. Insects usually have eggs and fungi have small fructifications like little white, grey or black dots.

Comment: Where are you growing the plants, indoors in the house, in a greenhouse, or somewhere else?

Comment: I am growing the plants in a container in my balcony. Plants do not get direct sunlight. I'll heck the leaves and reply

Comment: The leaves have nothing underneath like eggs or dots or any other patterns. They look perfect underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a leafhopper infestation - they cause these speckled, greyish markings on the leaves, but usually, leaves start to yellow and then go brown and dry, and I'm not seeing any like that in your image, though you do describe yellowing and drying.

Reference here, further down in the link http://www.offthegridnews.com/survival-gardening-2/top-17-problems-all-green-bean-growers-must-overcome/, unfortunately with no images. If it is leafhopper, insecticidal soap spray should take care of it, but you may need to repeat treat - row covers are a good way of preventing the problem, but your plants aren't in an ideal situation for using those.

Comment: I am not very sure it is leafhopper infestation. Let me add a few more details. The plants were unattended for 3-4 days and therefore I left the plants drainage with water. I might have overwatered the plants but not sure it can cause this issue. I have taken the plants on my terrace for good sunlight and hoping the plant recovers. Experts let me know if I need to replant them to a new container.

Comment: hard to say what an ideal pot size is without knowing the variety of bean

Comment: It's lablab. Also know as hyacinth bean